# How to perform this sort operation in python

Tags: python, iteration, generator, sorting

I am creating a module to analyse frequencies of patterns of tokens and delimiters in a given text split up into sentences.

I have a class "SequencePattern" which identifies one *element* (token or delimiter) in a set of tokenised sentences, where each SequencePattern has a list attribute "occurrences" consisting of tuples ( `n_sentence, n_element` ) where this particular element actual occurs.  Class SequencePattern has a class-level field, seq_patterns (a `set`), where all the individual SequencePattern instances are stored.

At this stage in the processing I only have single-element SequencePatterns, and have weeded out all such SequencePatterns having < 2 occurrences.  But SequencePattern is a subclass of `tuple` and the idea is now to find the "two element" SequencePatterns.

The next thing I need to do is to go through all the  one-element SequencePatterns which remain after weeding, identifying spots where you find two (or more) adjacent occurrences in the same sentence, i.e. where `n_sentence` is the same and `n_element` differs by 1.

So I need to do something along these lines:

```
occurrences_by_text_order = sorted( SequencePattern.seq_patterns.occurrences )
```

... but of course this doesn't work: I get

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'occurences'
```

Somehow I need to do an iteration of all SequencePatterns in seq_patterns and then, for each, a "nested" iteration of all occurrences for each of these... and I need to submit this mass of delivered tuples ( `n_sentence, n_element` ) to the `sorted` function.

I'm not an experienced Pythonista but I have a suspicion this is a job for a generator (?).  Can anyone help?

Comment: `sorted([x for x in SequencePattern.seq_patterns if len(x) == 1])` then look for adjacencies. _If_ I understand you, I think that's the next step.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem I asked, which is about iterating an iterating iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_occurrences():
    for seq_patt in SequencePattern.seq_patterns:
        for occurrence in seq_patt.occurrences:
            yield occurrence
occurrences_by_text_order = sorted( get_occurrences() )
```

The following then prints out a list of all the two-element sequences which *may* occur more than once (we now know that there is no possibility of two-element sequences with frequency > 1 occurring anywhere else):

```
prev_occurrence = None
for occurrence in sorted( occurrence for seq_patt in SequencePattern.seq_patterns for occurrence in seq_patt.occurrences ):
    if prev_occurrence and ( occurrence[ 0 ] == prev_occurrence[ 0 ] ) and ( occurrence[ 1 ] - prev_occurrence[ 1 ] == 1 ):  
        print( '# prev_occurrence %s occurrence: %s' % ( prev_occurrence, occurrence, ))
    prev_occurrence = occurrence
```

Comment: The same as this, but shorter, would be: `sorted(occurrence for seq_patt in SequencePattern.seq_patterns for occurrence in seq_patt.occurrences)`, although I did not get what you meant by *adjacent* and what you are trying to accomplish by sorting :)

Comment: @zvone thanks!  yes, sorry, it's actually quite simple but perhaps difficult to explain: I just want to find all elements (words or delimiters, i.e. non-word character sequences which separate the words) which occur more than once and which are next to each other... with a view to identifying two-element sequences which occur more than once.